# line 220 : return: can can only 'return' from a function or sourced script

Tags: shell-script, scripting

---

```
# C A L L   C U S T O M E R   D E F I N E D   P A R A M E T E R S

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cd /ERQ/100/DM/SCRIPTS

. ./DMPR2ERQ_log_interface.env



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# I N T E R N A L   S E C T I O N   ! ! !

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------



ORG_PWD=$PWD                                        # save directory where i am

COUNT=0                                             # actual value for retry logic

DATE=`date +'%y%m%d%H%M%S'`                         # creating time stamp

HUMAN_DATE=`date +'%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M:%S'`            # creating human readable time stamp

TMP_LOGFILE=$LOG_FILE_OUT.$$                        # temporary log file with PID

SLEEP_TIME=10                                       # how long to wait until check of file size



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# S E N D  E M A I L  O N  E R R O R

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------



SUBJECT="ERROR in script send_DMPR2ERQ_log.sh for Queue $QUEUE"



function error_mail

  {

  BODY="\nDate:   $HUMAN_DATE CET \

  \nScript: $ORG_PWD/send_DMPR2ERQ_log.sh \

  \nServer: `hostname` \

  \n\nThe following error occured: \

  \n---------------------------- \

  $ERROR_MSG"



  echo "$BODY" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL_ADDRESS"

  }



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# R E T U R N C O D E S

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RC_OK=0                                             # used in spoolin and spoolout

RC_PARAM_ERR=1                                      # used in spoolin and spoolout

RC_LOG_ERR=10                                       # used in spoolin and spoolout

RC_SI_PATH_ERR=11                                   # used in spoolin

RC_SO_PATH_ERR=12                                   # used in             spoolout

RC_ARCHIVE_PATH_ERR=13                              # used in spoolin

RC_ERROR_PATH_ERR=14                                # used in spoolin

RC_NO_FILES_ERR=15                                  # used in spoolin

RC_NO_QMGR_ERR=20                                   # used in spoolin and spoolout

RC_NO_QUEUE_ERR=21                                  # used in spoolin and spoolout

RC_NO_MQSERVER_ERR=22                               # used in spoolin and spoolout

RC_DPBAT_ERR=100                                    # used in spoolin and spoolout

RC_NO_FILENAME_ERR=300

RC_FILENAME_ERR=310



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# E R R O R   S E C T I O N

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SCRIPT_RC=$RC_OK                                    # init return code





if touch $LOG_FILE_OUT                              # log file access?

  then

    echo "\n["$DATE"]" > $TMP_LOGFILE

  else

    echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_LOG_ERR - Can't create $LOG_FILE_OUT"

    return $RC_LOG_ERR

fi



VARCHECK=`echo $MHQ_MQMGRNAME | wc -w`

if [ $VARCHECK = "0" ]                              # Queue Manager defined?

  then

    echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_NO_QMGR_ERR - Queue Manager not defined" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

    ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR: RC=$RC_NO_QMGR_ERR - Queue Manager not defined!"

    SCRIPT_RC=$RC_NO_QMGR_ERR

fi



VARCHECK=`echo $QUEUE | wc -w`

if [ $VARCHECK = "0" ]                              # Queue defined?

  then

    echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_NO_QUEUE_ERR - Target Queue not defined" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

    ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR: RC=$RC_NO_QUEUE_ERR - Target Queue not defined"

    SCRIPT_RC=$RC_NO_QUEUE_ERR

fi



VARCHECK=`echo $MQSERVER | wc -w`

if [ $VARCHECK = "0" ]                              # MQ Server connectivity defined?

  then

    echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_NO_MQSERVER_ERR - Variable MQSERVER not defined" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

    ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR: RC=$RC_NO_MQSERVER_ERR - Variable MQSERVER not defined"

    SCRIPT_RC=$RC_NO_MQSERVER_ERR

fi



VARCHECK=`echo $ARCHIVE_PATH | wc -w`

if [ $VARCHECK = "0" ]                              # Archive path defined?

  then

    echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_ARCHIVE_PATH_ERR - Variable ARCHIVE_PATH not defined" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

    ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR: RC=$RC_ARCHIVE_PATH_ERR - Variable ARCHIVE_PATH not defined"

    SCRIPT_RC=$RC_ARCHIVE_PATH_ERR

fi



VARCHECK=`echo $ERROR_PATH | wc -w`

if [ $VARCHECK = "0" ]                              # Error path defined?

  then

    echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_ERROR_PATH_ERR - Variable ERROR_PATH not defined" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

    ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR: RC=$RC_ERROR_PATH_ERR - Variable ERROR_PATH not defined"

    SCRIPT_RC=$RC_ERROR_PATH_ERR

fi



VARCHECK=`echo $SI_PATH | wc -w`

if [ $VARCHECK != "0" ]                             # parameter SI_PATH defined?

  then

    cd $SI_PATH

    CD_RC=$?

    if [ $CD_RC = "0" ]

      then

                echo "--> Changed to spoolin directory $SI_PATH successfully." >> $TMP_LOGFILE

      else

                echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_SI_PATH_ERR - could not change to spoolin directory $SI_PATH" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

                ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR: RC=$RC_SI_PATH_ERR - could not change to spoolin directory $SI_PATH"

                SCRIPT_RC=$RC_SI_PATH_ERR

    fi

  else

    echo "ERROR: RC=$RC_SI_PATH_ERR - no variable for spoolin directory specified" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

    ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR: RC=$RC_SI_PATH_ERR - no variable for spoolin directory specified"

    SCRIPT_RC=$RC_SI_PATH_ERR

fi



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# S P O O L I N

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if [ $SCRIPT_RC -eq "0" ]

then

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # F I L E   P O L L I N G

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cd /srv/ERQ_P2M_DUALACCESS/DM/LOG

    cp `ls -tr DMPR2ERP* | tail -1` /ERQ/100/DM/OUTBOUND



cd /ERQ/100/DM/OUTBOUND   

for FILE in `ls -l DMPR2ERP*`; do

  if [ -f $FILE ]; then

    FILE_SIZE_1=`ls -l $FILE | awk '{ printf("%s.%s\n", $9, $5) }'`

    sleep $SLEEP_TIME

    FILE_SIZE_2=`ls -l $FILE | awk '{ printf("%s.%s\n", $9, $5) }'`

    if [ $FILE_SIZE_1 = $FILE_SIZE_2 ]; then

      SI_FILENAME=$FILE

      echo "  > Putting file $SI_PATH/$SI_FILENAME to Queue $QUEUE" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # D E T E R M I N E   S P O O L I N    O P T I O N

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        SI_CMD="si(si-id=$QUEUE, si-filename=$SI_FILENAME); end; "

        DPBAT_RC=0

        echo $SI_CMD | $MHQ_HOME/dpbat >> $TMP_LOGFILE 2>&1

        DPBAT_RC=$?

        echo "Return Code (RC) DPBAT = $DPBAT_RC" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

        if [ $DPBAT_RC = "0" ]

        then

          #----------------------------------------------------------------------------

          # if RC=0 the spool-in was succesful, move to archive directory

          #----------------------------------------------------------------------------

          echo "--> File $SI_PATH/$SI_FILENAME successfully put to Queue $QUEUE." >> $TMP_LOGFILE

                  mv $SI_PATH/$SI_FILENAME $ARCHIVE_PATH

                  echo "--> File $SI_PATH/$SI_FILENAME moved to archive directory. \n " >> $TMP_LOGFILE

        else

          #----------------------------------------------------------------------------

          # if RC<>0 the spool-in was NOT succesful, move to error directory

          #----------------------------------------------------------------------------

          SCRIPT_RC=`expr $DPBAT_RC + $RC_DPBAT_ERR`  # some dpbat errors found!

          echo "--> Ended without putting file to Queue. (RC DPBAT: $DPBAT_RC)" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

          ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nEnded without putting file to Queue. (RC DPBAT: $DPBAT_RC)"

                  mv $SI_PATH/$SI_FILENAME $ERROR_PATH

          echo "--> Moved file to error directory $ERROR_PATH." >> $TMP_LOGFILE

          ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nMoved file to error directory $ERROR_PATH."

        fi

      fi

    fi

  done

else

echo "File $FILE does not exists" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

SCRIPT_RC=15

fi



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Analyze global error return code and send email if necessary

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if [ $SCRIPT_RC -ne "0" ]

then

  echo "ERROR occured. (RC SCRIPT: $SCRIPT_RC)" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

  ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nERROR occurred. (RC SCRIPT: $SCRIPT_RC)"

  if [ $ERROR_NOTIFICATION = "y" ]

    then

      echo "Notification sent to $EMAIL_ADDRESS" >> $TMP_LOGFILE

      ERROR_MSG=$ERROR_MSG"\nNotification sent to $EMAIL_ADDRESS"

      error_mail

  fi

fi



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Append temporary log to main log and delete temporary log file

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cat $TMP_LOGFILE >> $LOG_FILE_OUT

rm -f $TMP_LOGFILE

cd $ORG_PWD

return $SCRIPT_RC
```

Comment: This is a difficult one! 1.) What ist the question 2.) Where is line 220 ?

Comment: the last line in script "return $SCRIPT_RC".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return value error in bash scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439414/return-value-error-in-bash-scripts)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `return` statement can only be used to return an exit status from a shell function or a dot-script (a script being sourced using either `.` (dot) or `source` in shells that support that alias for `.`).  Shell functions and dot-scripts are very similar in that respect.

The code that you show contains a `return` statement as its last executable statement, and this may be what throws the error if you ran the script as an ordinary script.

It may well be that your script is supposed to be executed as

```
. ./script.sh
```

rather than as

```
./script.sh
```

or that *another* script is supposed to do that (it's unknown). If you do run the script with the dot command (or `source` in e.g. `bash`), note that you will be left in `/ERQ/100/DM/SCRIPTS` after the end of the execution of the script (since this is where the script changes the working directory upon exiting).

Note also that the script uses some strange code to do ordinary things.  For example, to test whether `$ARCHIVE_PATH` is defined it does

```
VARCHECK=`echo $ARCHIVE_PATH | wc -w`
if [ $VARCHECK = "0" ]
```

This test would not test whether it was undefined but whether it was empty (or contained only characters from `$IFS`).  In fact, more than half the script is taken up by statements verifying configuration settings.

Instead, one could use

```
if [ "${ARCHIVE_PATH-is unset}" = "is unset" ]
```

or, in `bash`,

```
if [ ! -v ARCHIVE_PATH ]
```

or, if you just want to test for an empty value,

```
if [ -z "$ARCHIVE_PATH" ]
```

The script also uses `ls` in multiple places to get lists of files, which is less than ideal.

Comment: The script gives the above error when it is executed through SM69 whereas when it is executed as './script.sh' it works fine . Is there any other option to remove this error in SM69?

Comment: Both return statements (`return $RC_LOG_ERR` and `return $SCRIPT_RC`) should result in an error "./script.sh: line xy: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script" when executed as script.

Comment: @bhavnapatil I don't know how SM69 executes the script or what shell it uses to execute the script. Some shells would probably be ok with executing it as `./script.sh` but as I don't even know what SM69 is I can't say anything about it.  There is _no_ indication as to what shell is being used here.

Comment: @bhavnapatil Also, you should _never ever_ "enable options to remove errors"!!  Errors are removed by writing correct code.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok got it.